$T$ compact operator, Let $\Delta^*_{\bar{\lambda}}$ subspace of $X^*$. Prove $\Delta^*_{\bar{\lambda}} = \bar{\Delta^*_{\bar{\lambda}}}$
We have proved the following claim:

Let T be compact operator and $\lambda \neq 0$. Then $\Delta_\lambda = \bar{\Delta _\lambda}$.

Now there is the corollary:

$T$ compact operator, Let $\Delta^*_{\bar{\lambda}}$ subspace of $X^*$. Prove $\Delta^*_{\bar{\lambda}} = \bar{\Delta^*_{\bar{\lambda}}}$

I know the proof is simple since I can choose $T^*$ and $\lambda$ to be $\bar{\lambda}$ in the claim.
But I tried solving it without it:
$\Delta^*_{\bar{\lambda}} = Im T^* _{\bar{\lambda}} = \{y\in X^* s.t \exists x\in X^*: T^* _{\bar{\lambda}}x = y\}$
And then I thought I can do some manipulation on the set and use $\Delta_\lambda = \bar{\Delta _\lambda}$.
Does somebody know if its possible?
Thank you :)
Might add that we talked about the space of bounded operators and saw that if $A:X\mapsto Y$ then $\langle Ax,y\rangle =\langle x,A^{*}y\rangle$. I thought I might use something similar to this

What are $\Delta_{\lambda}$, $\Delta^{}_{\lambda}$ and $T^{}_{\lambda}$?

$\Delta_\lambda = Im T_\lambda=Im(T-\lambda I)$, $\Delta^_\lambda = Im(T^-\lambda I)$, $T^_\lambda = T^-\lambda I$ where $T^*$ is the dual of $T$
I'm using Functional Analysis An introduction by Yuli Edelman, Vitali Milman and Antonis Tsolomitis, the question is from page 79

Thanks for the information. Are you also able to state what $\overline{\Delta_{\lambda}}$ is? It may also be a good idea to include this information in the question as it is not standard notation as far as I am aware and it is essential information to being able to solve the problem.

$\bar A$ is the closure of set A

I don't think there is a way to perform simple manipulations on the set $\Delta_{\overline{\lambda}}^{}$ to show that it is closed without directly using that $T^{}$ is compact. I did find a way to prove it without directly using that $T^{*}$ is compact, but the proof is quite involved, so I am not sure it is what you are looking for. I can type it up and post it as an answer if you are interested.
